# Copy and process image using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Currently, we have CarrierWave resizing image to 3 sizes in the model.

Model.rb

```
...
mount_uploader :image Uploader
...
```

Uploader.rb

```
...
version :small 
...
version :medium
...
version :large
...
```

We would like to add one more field into a Model.
The processed_image is the same as image ( 3 sizes ), plus adding a blur filter into it.

Model.rb

```
...
mount_uploader :image Uploader
mount_uploader :processed_image ProcessedUploader
...
```

ProcessedUploader.rb

```
...
version :small 
    ## add blur processed
...
version :medium
    ## add blur processed
...
version :large
    ## add blur processed
...
```

How to copy from the original :image to the :processed_image and have it processed after the image is uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Use another field processed_image; 
   write this in your model:

   before_create :copy_image

   def copy_image

   ```
   self.processed_image = self.image.file
   ```

   end
2. Use single field image; 
   Just use different versions like small_blurred, medium_blurred, large_blurred etc and process blur effect on those versions.